# Is it possible to know in which FLOW a specific LWC is used?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

Due to project and requirements, I need to update a Flow that uses a specific LWC. I know the LWC that I need to change but I don't know the flow in which this LWC is used. Project has a lot of Flows and Subflows and it takes a lot of time checking one by one until find LWC.

Is it any way or tool to check in which flow a LWC is being used?

Comment: What about retrieval of all flows with sfdx/metadata api and search for screens with LWC in it via VS code/grep/awk or any other tools?

Comment: For the daring (and Sandboxes): Try to delete the LWC. You'd be stopped and get a link to the flow. - But don't blame me, if it turns out the LWC had not been used ;-)

Comment: @FelixvanHove You mean, you don't use source control, just in case? :D

Comment: @kurunve I did this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the easiest: Remove the following line from the XML configuration file of your LWC and try to save it to the org:

```
<target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
```

Salesforce's complain will include references to specific flow versions. Then revert your config.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to query the [MetadataComponentDependency](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm) API to determine every Flow that a LWC is used in (as well as any other dependencies).